# How to add a screen switcher component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-component

Being a newbie to the field of app development, I actually don't know the name of this UI component [image: 1].

This component basically act as a switcher between two screen, which shows up `Explore` screen when **`Explore`** is clicked and `My Community` screen when **`My Community`** is clicked

Someone please help me to know what to call this component and which npm package need to be used to deploy it.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: It's a `toggle-button` or simply `switch`
See: https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch#example

This also might help you: https://reactnativeforyou.com/how-to-add-a-switch-toggle-button-in-react-native/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [switch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch) component and its boolean value to conditionally display different screens/components.

Basic example using [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

```
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
  
return (
  <View>
    <Switch
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
      {isEnabled ? <Text>Placerholder Screen 1</Text> : <Text>Placerholder Screen 2</Text>}
    </View>
  );
```

But in this situation I would advise you to use Tabs instead of a Switch. [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) is a great library to help you with this. You may want to look at the [bottom tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/), [material bottom tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator) or [material top tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator).